# Random numbers generator

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, monte-carlo

If I know how to generate random numbers from Gaussian distribution (using Box-Muller method), how can I generate random numbers from distribution with pdf $\frac{x+e^{-x^2/2}}{\text{erf}{(1/\sqrt{2})}\sqrt{2\pi}}$ on interval $[-1,1]$?

I have to create generator of such numbers in Matlab but I can't figure out what is a procedure to generate them.

Comment: your fonction is not a density (takes negative values)

Comment: @roger Thank you, I didn't pay enough attention.
Original question is to generate random numbers from distribution $\rho(x)$ approximately equals $x+e^{-x^2/2}$, $x\in [-1,1]$. What I did is that I calculated integral of that function and found a constant such that $\int^{1}_{1} a\rho(x) dx=1$ and I got $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}*erf(1/\sqrt{2})}$.
But it obviously doesn't work in this case. What should I do?

Comment: I don't know what is meant by approximately equals. If you want to generate a random variable whose density is a convex combination of two densities, what you can do is pick at random one density or the other. For instance let $X$ and $Y$ be independent with densities $f$ and $g$ and $Z$ a Bernoulli $B(p)$ rv independent from the rest. Then $ZX +(1-Z)Y$ has density $pf + (1-p)g$.

Comment: But $\int^{1}_{-1} a*x dx=0$ for every constant $a$ so it is not pdf for any constant $a$.

Comment: yes obviously, you can either consider $\vert x \vert$ or $x + cste$ or something like that

Comment: Thanks. I will try like that.